# Ruby capybara Action buider

Tags: ruby, capybara, appium

I'm using capybara in ruby with appium, and I need to emulate the send_keys and then an enter:

```
private final Actions act;
this.act = new Actions(baseTest.getDriver());

public void scannerSend(String value){
  act.sendKeys(value);
  act.sendKeys("\uE007").perform();
 }
```

The code above is in java, what I need and can't find is the equivalent in ruby using capybara. 
What I need to do is send a string and then emulate the press enter event.

Comment: Are you using capybara-webkit or just capybara?

Comment: Capyabara im just using

Comment: You might want to add info about which driver you're using too.  The methods for sending special keys are often driver specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're acting on some part of the view rather than the whole thing.
Try:

```
fill_in("foo-id", :with => 'my text')
find("#foo-id").native.send_keys :enter
```

This should send enter to the element with id `foo-id`.
Due to the range in drivers you may need to make significant adjustments.  The above is how one might do it with selenium.

Comment: What im tring to emulate is to emulate a Scanner, scanning a barcode, but ill try that approach

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the master branch of Capybara with selenium you can do

```
find('#foo-id').send_keys('my text', :enter)
```

This syntax will probably be supported by most of the other drivers once Capybara 2.5 is released